# Failing the template function lookup

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

Consider following example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

template < typename A >
int boo( const boost::optional< A > &a );

template < typename A >
int foo( const A &a )
{
    return boo( a );
}

template < typename A >
int boo( const boost::optional< A > & )
{
    return 3;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "foo = " << foo( 3 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "boo = " << boo( 3 ) << std::endl;
}
```

Compiling this using g++ 4.3.0 throws the next compiling errors:

```
dfg.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
dfg.cpp:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘boo(int)’
dfg.cpp: In function ‘int foo(const A&) [with A = int]’:
dfg.cpp:24:   instantiated from here
dfg.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘boo(const int&)’
```

What should I do differently (if possible with references from the C++ standard)? 
Why is it happening and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**

The fix is to create the correct type in `foo`:

```
template < typename A >
int foo( const A &a )
{
    const boost::optional< A > optA( a );
    return boo( optA );
}
```

But the questions still stands: why is it not created automatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return boo( a );
```

Here type of `a` is `int`, and there is no function with name `boo` which accepts argument of type `int`. Hence you see this error:

> dfg.cpp:25: error: no matching
>   function for call to ‘boo(int)’

Even if `int` can be *implicitly* converted into `boost::optional<int>`, the compiler cannot deduce the template argument for `boost::optional<T>` from the calling site. It's one of the non-deduced contexts where you *explicitly* need to mention the type as,

```
   return boo<A>(a);
```

The Standard says in $14.8.2.1,

> if a template-parameter is not used in
>   any of the function parameters of a
>   function template, or is used only in
>   a non-deduced context, **its
>   corresponding template-argument cannot
>   be deduced from a function call and
>   the template-argument must be
>   explicitly specified**.

Comment: Yes, but boost::optional< int > should be created, no?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, you need to explicitly specify the type when calling `boo`, i.e.

```
return boo<A>( a );
```

and

```
std::cout << "boo = " << boo<int>( 3 ) << std::endl;
```

EDIT: removed my explanation, it was rubbish, Nawaz's explanation is better..

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that because `optional<int>` has an implicit constructor from int, the compiler should know that is the type you are trying to create.

Template type deduction does not extend to that.

You could write your own template of boo with the one that takes optional as a generalisation

```
template< typename A > int boo( const A& a );
template < typename A >
int boo( const boost::optional< A > & )
{
    return 3;
}

template < typename A >
int boo( const A & a )
{
    return boo<A>(boost::optional(a)); // allows implicit conversion
}
```